# how to backtransform prevalence estimate following double arcsine transform using (=meta package)

Tags: r, metafor

I'm new to posting on StackOverflow; apologies in advance for any inadvertent faux pas.

I'm running a meta-analysis of proportion exploring the prevalence of patients with psychosis with an MRI abnormality (as a binary variable ie yes/no)

I've transformed the data using Freeman-Tukey Double arcsine transformation (to stabilise the variance). However, I'm struggling to back transform the results to report the prevalence(code below).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks

`meta::metaprop(abnormality_count, sample_count, author_year, data=data, sm="PFT",                                             method.tau="DL", method.ci="NAsm",backtransf=TRUE)`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I tested your code with a sample dataset. I get backtransformed proportions, as expected. Could yo explain in greater etail your problem? What is the output of your `metaprop` command? What is the expected result? Please, edit your question and add more information.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly Marco, much appreciated (I didn't expect such a rapid response!). Hopefully, I've answered your query below – do let me know if I’m missing any details.

In brief, using the code pasted, when I run a summary of the model, the prevalence estimate (base on a random-effects model) looks to be correct at 0.05 (ie 5%). However, when I try to isolate the prevalence estimate (using the code `model$TE.random`) the estimate increases to 0.24 (ie 24%).

I assume this difference is due to the statistic not being back-transformed. Any advice is appreciated.